# Django - How to control 'add another' links in django-nested-admin areas

Tags: django, user-interface, admin

[image: Django Nested Admin]

I have a very complicated object structure that the django admin section handles like a champ. As you can see below there are sub-references to other objects or even the same object. In many cases the sub objects are created in a certain pattern and I'd like to be able to generate stubs for that pattern. What i'd like to be able to do is I guess customize what happens when you click on the 'Add another Crafted Item' link, or add another link that will add multiple sub-item stubs.

Right now if you click on that link, you get ONE stub with default values in it from the model object. I wanna do the same thing, but I want to be able to do more than one and be able to specify different default values than what are specified in the model object.

Does anyone have any idea how I can tap into that functionality? Is there a name for it or something?

thanks for the assistance,
EK